# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid error

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This question has been asked a lot, but still, nothing seems to be working. My application runs perfectly in testing, but when run on heroku, I get the error 500 saying "we're sorry , but something went wrong." I've checked the log files for the server, and my error seems to be here somewhere:

```
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 117.192.23.223 at 2012-10-21 15:29:40 +0000
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whispering-coast-7415.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=301 bytes=115
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/movies" for 117.192.23.223 at 2012-10-21 15:29:40 +0000
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by MoviesController#index as HTML
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whispering-coast-7415.herokuapp.com/movies dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=728
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  column "movies.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies"  GROUP BY rating
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]:                ^
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /movies] miss
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "movies".* FROM "mo
vies"  GROUP BY rating):
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:11:in `index'
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/movie.rb:4:in `get_ratings'
2012-10-21T15:29:40+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-21T15:29:41+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whispering-coast-7415.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=0
2012-10-21T15:29:41+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /favicon.ico] stale, invalid, store
```

Comment: Can you please add your MovieController Index action to the question?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL (on Heroku) requires you to GROUP BY *all* the columns in the SELECT list so in this case instead of:

```
SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies"  GROUP BY rating
```

you might want to do something like:

```
SELECT rating FROM "movies" GROUP BY rating
```

or in Rails:

```
Movie.select(:rating).group(:rating)
```